# Correct way of writing tests for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

So I just stambled upon this issue. I would like to ask about the best way of solving this issue. This is relevant part of my `App.js` code:

```
addTask = (text) => {
    const {tasks} = this.state;
    tasks.push({text});
    this.setState({tasks});
};

<AddTaskConfirmBtn
    text={
        this.state.newTaskValue // This is just a simple state string
    }
    addTask={
        this.addTask
    }/>
```

`AddTask` test

```
it('should addTask', function () {
    wrapper
        .instance()
        .addTask('testing');
    expect(
        wrapper
            .state('tasks')
    ).toEqual([
        {text: 'make todo with hooks'},
        {text: 'write tests'},
        {text: 'do the daily'},
        {text: 'testing'},
    ])
});
```

`AddTaskConfirmBtn` code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <button
            onClick={
                    this.props
                        .addTask // This is the issue. This adds an object to the array. It is solved below
            }>
            Add task
        </button>
    );
}
```

// just for reference. This is the way I solved the problem

```
render() {
    return (
        <button
            onClick={
                () => {
                    this.props
                        .addTask(this.props.text)
                }
            }>
            Add task
        </button>
    );
}
```

And here is my test:

```
describe('<AddTaskConfirmBtn/>',
    function () {
        let wrapper;
        let addTaskMock = jest.fn();
        beforeEach(
            function () {
                wrapper = shallow(
                    <AddTaskConfirmBtn addTask={addTaskMock}/>
                );
            }
        );
        it('should addTaskToTasks onClick',
            function () {
                wrapper
                    .find('button')
                    .simulate('click');
                expect(addTaskMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            }
        );
    }
)
```

First of all I am in the process of learning Unit testing and TDD, so please be gentle with my stupidity.

Now to my issue. I was testing my code the way seen above. So adding the correct value and pushing it to the state, and comparing. The AddTaskConfirmBtn was just checking if the method was called.

But I just realized there is an error I didn't account for with my testing. I was pushing the wrong thing into the array (I believe it was the event object I was pushing into the state). I fixed it, but the interesting thing was the tests didn't catch it. Obviously because I didn't write them this way.

So my question is, should I worry about it? Should I account for situations like this in my tests? Or is it just something that happens? Or maybe I should put safeguards in the method itself? Like

```
addTask = (text) => {
    if (typeof text !== "string") {
        console.log("text is not a string", text);
        return null;
    }
    const {tasks} = this.state;
    tasks.push({text});
    this.setState({tasks});
};
```

How should it be done in the best way possible?

Comment: `tasks.push({text});` this is modifying the current state directly, always use `setState` and always create copies.

Comment: I thing thought that's what I'm doing. I was creating a local copy of state, then using setState. But if I'm wrong please correct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the general good practice is to handle all the scenarios that are inside the component and not the things that other components will send. For example in your case, it is a good idea to test what type of object is being sent.

So, you could use the function like `toHaveBeenCalledWith` to test what type of data is sent. Building a safeguard is always a good idea.

Comment: So should I test the type of the variable passed to the method in a test or in the method itself? Or maybe both?

Comment: You can create a test for your function with a mock parameter and test the response to equal null or not null.